# unable to open ubuntu using Bootable ubuntu on my pendrive

Tags: installation, usb, vaio, sony

I am Using Sony Vaio VGN-CR220E and windows vista,I created bootable ubuntu on my kingston 8GB pendrive using universal usb installer setup.I changed Boot options i.e enabled external usb drive and changed the USB priority to first and my harddrive to second  i boot options.

but after restarting i am unable to boot it from pendrive.the cursor is just blinking on the blank screen.unable to see OS select options.

How can i rectify this ...Please Help me

Comment: Check, in BIOS, that your pendrive is listed as external usb. Sometimes BIOS recognises it as a hard disk drive, so, in this case what you have to do is set BIOS to boot from hard disk drive as first option (priority) and, in the hard disk drive list you have to place your pendrive at top of the HDD list. Save and exit.

Answer (score 0):

Check, in BIOS, that your pendrive is listed as external usb. Sometimes BIOS recognises it as a hard disk drive, so, in this case what you have to do is set BIOS to boot from hard disk drive as first option (priority) and, in the hard disk drive list you have to place your pendrive at top of the HDD list. Save and exit.

Answer (score 0):

How did you create the bootable pen drive ? If your BIOS settings are correct, Try this:
https://rufus.akeo.ie/
It has worked for me every time I needed to boot Linux from a pen drive